# Responsive boostrap rails nav-bar drop down stays down when i collapse page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When i try to run the sample Starter template from the Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 get started page and i try to collapse the page to smaller size the navbar items don't collapse into the corner like they should in the demo but stay as pulled down pulldown. 
i am using Rails with

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass' and 
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3' [in assets]
```

my application.js file includes:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

and my boostrap_and_overides.css.scss file includes:

```
@import "bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 60px; }
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

i love the idea of responsive bootstrap but cant get it to work
here is the main code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1

 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the sample code posted to Github: https://github.com/dao888/raboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. For the record, i was using the gem 'rails', '3.2.7' and when i updated to gem 'rails', '3.2.13' the problem was resolved.